# Raise volume above recommended level? message

Tags: audio

Why do I see this message on my phone every few weeks?

> Raise volume above recommended level? Listening at high volume for long periods may damage your hearing.

When the message is displayed the volume decreases suddenly. Can I turn this off?

Answer (score 4):

It's a European law which states you must be reminded every 20 hours of listening:

> The user can choose to override the limit so that the sound level can be increased up to maximum 100dB. If the user overrides the limit, warnings about the risks must be repeated every 20 hours of listening time.

http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-21294537